# FileSystemWatcher not firing events on Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I have developed a web service which monitors certain directory for PDF files.
Service was tested on different systems including several Windows Server 2012 instances and works fine.

The problem occurs when deploying to customer's server - file watcher does not raise any events.

I created a small test tool to diagnose the problem.

Besides FileSystemWatcher it also has a timer, which simply updates the list of files in the watched folder each 0.5 seconds.

[Screenshot of the tool at my test server (on the left) and on customer's (on the right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4hOk.png)

As you can see, the PDF file is displayed in the list on the right (populated on a timer event), while list on the left is empty (populated on FileSystemWatcher events).

Log on the bottom also does not show any file changes.

The customer is government organization, which has strict security setup and I guess the issue has something to do with it, but:

- tool does not throw any errors (I make sure to log every possible error)
- we tried running the tool as Administrator (same result)
- generally, target folder contents can be read without any issues (see the screenshot)

What complicates the whole process is that I don't have direct access to the target system and can only send the executables with some instructions.

Does anybody have an idea why could this happen?

[Source code of the test tool](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zp827elgvvheha8/TestFileEvents.zip?dl=0)

Comment: What I would probably try would be to increase the FileSystemWatcher.InternalBufferSize to maybe 65536. Additionally you dont need to handle the Synchronisation Context as you can just assign this (the form) to the FileSystemWatcher.SynchronizingObject. Even though I dont think the second one will solve your problem. Another problem could be the UAC

Comment: Thank you for looking into this.
I am almost sure it has something to do with security resrictions.
I also asked customer to run similar tool from here:
[link] (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/58740/FileSystemWatcher-Pure-Chaos-Part-of)
Result is the same - no events displayed. Tested on 2 servers within same organization.

Comment: Eventually this was solved - the problem was due to folder security rights.

Comment: @Sergey , I am dealing with exact same problem and have tried all kinds of tricks but nothing is working. Do you remember what "folder security rights" were missing?